# Java save method only get the id and the other attribut are NULL

Tags: java, jsf, ejb

I develop an application in java with EJB and JSF(primefaces). Here is my problem. I have a item `save` method in my application. I would like to retrieve the data from the `File` table, but when debugging I see that the method only retrieves the id from the form and the rest of the attributes return null. where did I do something wrong. thank you in advance.

```
public String savedol(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        Long idFile = (Long) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("idFile");
        if (this.doleance.getId() == null) {
            idFile = file.getId();
            this.fiche.setId(idFile );
            this.fiche.getId();
            this.fiche.getCustumer();
            this.fiche.getCustumer().getCountry();
            doleance.setFiche(fiche);
            this.complaintsDetailsService.saveOne(doleance);
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Constante.SAVE_SUCCESSFUL));
            this.complaint= new ComplaintsDetails();
            this.file= new File();
            return "/fileComplaints/complaints.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        } else {
            this.complaintsDetailsService.updateOne(complaint);
            this.file = new File();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Constante.MODIF_SUCCESSFUL));
        }
        return "/fileComplaints/complaints.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Constante.SAVE_UNDONE));
        this.complaintsDetailsService.updateOne(doleance);
        this.fileService.updateOne(fiche);
    }
    this.file = new File();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all start by creating an [mcve] and read [ask]. It helps you narrow down the problem. Impossible to help with this question. And please post version info. In addition the way you read `idFile` is very oldschool (effectively it was never needed in JSF, it is sort of how the jsp/servlet and php people did things) and I only see you 'reading' this value...

Comment: And you should delete your email because you will WANT to come here to see the answers :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, concerning the reading of the `idFile`, how do you advise me to read it thank you. sorry i didn't read the question before sending.

Comment: Leave that part in place for now, focus on the other things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i found a mistake 
Indeed. I did the value intensification with the service and now it gets all the class in parameter as follows.

```
public String savedol(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
try {
    Long idFile = (Long) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("idFile ");
        this.file = this.ficheService.find(idFile );
        doleance.setFile(file);
        doleance.setClient(file.getCustumer());
        doleance.setPays(file.getCustumer().getCountry());
        this.complaintsDetailsService.saveOne(doleance);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Constante.SAVE_SUCCESSFUL));
        this.complaint= new ComplaintsDetails();
        this.file= new File();
        return "/fileComplaints/complaints.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        this.complaintsDetailsService.updateOne(complaint);
        this.file = new File();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Constante.MODIF_SUCCESSFUL));
    }
    return "/fileComplaints/complaints.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Constante.SAVE_UNDONE));
    this.complaintsDetailsService.updateOne(doleance);
    this.fileService.updateOne(fiche);
}
this.file = new File();
return null;}
```

It saves now the values ​​of Client and Recovered Countries from File.
with this `this.file = this.ficheService.find(idFile );`

If this can help someone else.

Comment: Thanks! Much better.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if anyone could help me improve my code and make it cleaner and more professional. Thank you.